# Getting Css Variable Value at Runtime

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

I am working on an app written in Polymer.

I have some CSS variables defined like this:

```
:root {
  --my-option-1: #ff8a80;
  --my-option-2: #4a148c;
  --my-option-3: #8c9eff;
}
```

The user literally chooses "1", "2", or "3". I have a function that looks like this:

```
// The v parameter will be 1, 2, or 3
function getOptionColor(v) {
  var name = '--my-option-' + v;
  return ?;
}
```

I need `getOptionColor` to return `#ff8a80`, `#4a148c`, or `#8c9eff` based on the value entered into the function. However, I do not know how to get the value of a CSS variable at runtime. Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Maybe take a look at: https://www.broken-links.com/2014/08/28/css-variables-updating-custom-properties-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to read and write CSS variables using

```
this.customStyle['--my-toolbar-color']
```

or

```
this.customStyle['--my-toolbar-color'] = value;
```

if this is executed from within a Polymer element and the variables are declared in a style tag in this element.
There might be a way for global variables but I haven't discovered it yet.

Comment: When I use `this.customStyle['--my-var-name']` I see 'undefined'. I tried using one of the baked in style names like `this.customStyle['--paper-deep-purple-800']`. However, I still got 'undefined' for that as well.

Comment: AFAIK the variable needs to be declared in the elements style where you use `this.customStyle['--my-var-name']`. As I wrote in my answer, I don't know a way to access them globally.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API that you can use that retreives stylesheets with javascript. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets

Use the documentation and you will see how to iterate through the stylesheet properties.

Comment: I wanted to up vote this, but it is a link-only answer. Can you provide a basic usage example in addition to the link?

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to let me get the value of a CSS variable though. I looped through all of the stylesheets and looked at the cssRules. I did not see any variable names.